# Cakephp 3 Cannot convert value to bool issue

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x, toarray

I am execute flowing query .

```
$query = $busdetails
      ->find('list',['keyField' => 'id','valueField' => 'bus_name'])
      ->where(['status'=>1,'is_approved'=>1]); 

pr($query->toArray());
```

It works fine if some results found but if no results found then it shows an error Cannot convert value to bool issue. Thanks

Comment: can you provide the actual message received ?

Answer (score 1):

update cakephp library file.--

```
cakephp/src/Database/Type/BoolType.php
```

Change

```
if ($value === true || $value === false)
```

by

```
if ($value === true || $value === false || is_null($value))
```

From more detail --

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/7583

Comment: Given that this is the actual problem, the solution should be to update the CakePHP dependency, not to make manual changes in the core that are going to be lost with the next update!